# Need to automate changes to my Display settings

Tags: display, windows, script, remote-desktop, dual-screen

As a former engineer, I know that if I find myself doing the same thing over and over, I should be able to automate that process.  So here goes:

Due to things beyond my control, every time I log into my work PC via Microsoft Remote Desktop (from my M1 Mac Mini w/ Monterey 12.3.1), the MSRD session maximizes and uses BOTH my monitors (in my case, I cannot edit the .rdp file to fix this. It just launches from a web-button.  I could edit it back when I was using Windows/Edge).  To circumvent this, I must first mirror one display to the other, then launch the MSRD session (which now maximizes to just "one" display), then I return to dual-screen mode.  This is exhausting!

To further get around this headache, I have recently resorted to remoting into an older Windows PC (on my home LAN) and logging into work from there and working through a window-within-a-window monstrosity.  Now granted, this option works very well given my gigabit wired LAN and I haven't noticed any performance lag, it's just ridiculous that I have to do this.

Can someone help me automate a quick-mirror macro needed above or offer any other advice?

Thanks a ton!

-Scott

Comment: Why can't you set the screen size from the RDC Edit panel? Mine just remember what they were last set to. 'Fit session to window' should be the one, then whatever you drag the Mac window to is what the Win session fits in, every time. [I haven't used it for a while, as I've managed to get rid of every Win machine in the building at last.. so my 'Win' now runs in a VM on another Mac]

Comment: You say, "I could edit it back when I was using Windows/Edge." which is a little confusing as Edge is just a web browser and all versions of MS Remote Desktop (Mac & Windows) offer the ability to edit the .RDP file within the app. **ALSO** an .RDP file is nothing more than a plain text file, you can edit it in any text editor

Comment: So, my company's remote access process uses a web-based icon to launch the MS Remote Desktop session.  When I launch from a Windows browser (like Edge), it downloads the rdp file and I can edit and change the settings.  On my Mac (using Chrome) I cannot 'intercept' the .rdp file before it launches and edit the display settings and I am not aware of a way to change those settings once the session is running.

Comment: RDP files don‘t autolaunch per default, is there something in Chrome‘s configuration? Or could you try a different browser?

Comment: It's some Javascript thing that automatically launches MS Remote Desktop.  There's nothing I can do on my Mac to get the rdp file.  In Windows, it behaves differently:  It downloads the rdp file and then you can click-to-open or right-click to edit.  Frustrating!

Comment: Also, as part of the security protocol, the remote system issues a new (unique) RDP file every time.  So I can't just get one, edit and use it over and over.  On my windows system, there would be dozens of old (useless) RDP files in my Downloads folder.  On my Mac, there are no RDP files.  Hmmm.

Comment: By the way, I'm using Chrome on both Mac & PC and getting the 2 different results described above.  If I use Safari, the results are the same, MSRD launches.

Comment: How about right click, download link as… ?